# How to take multiple inputs in the same line in C++?

Tags: c++

I am working on a program but now I am stuck with a problem and the problem is I want to enter two numbers but with the cursor in same line. Whenever I enter any number and press enter it moves to the next line but I want it on the same line. How do I take multiple inputs in the same line?

Comment: The console/terminal doesn't work that way. You can use GNU readline() or NCurses to try to get around it. Or you can put your I/O in a GUI. You've probably been downvoted because this is a common question, and the correct answer is almost always "don't do that."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this simply by **cascading** the the `cin` operator. If you write a code in this way:

```
int a,b;
cout << "Enter value of a" << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "Enter value of b" << endl;
cin >> b;
```

then the program execution would be in this way:

```
Enter value of a
10
Enter value of b
20
```

But to do this in a single line, you can write the code in this way:

```
cout << "Enter the values of a and b" << endl;
cin >> a >> b; //cascading the cin operator
```

The program execution now goes thus:

```
Enter the values of a and b
10 20
```

If you enter both values this way (separating them with a space), then it works the way you want it to - being in the same line.
Also, in the first snippet, if you remove the `endl` keyword, you can also have it all in one line but I don't think that's what you want.

Also see: [CASCADING OF I/O OPERATORS | easyprograming](https://easyprograming.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/cascading-of-io-operators/).

Comment: I suggest using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` because you have no need to flush here as `std::cout` and `std::cin` are internally coupled.

Comment: @JanNilsFerner Sure.

Answer (score 3):

For two variable `a` and `b`, You can write the code in this way,

```
cout << "Enter the values of a and b: ";
cin >> a >> b;
```

The program will be executed as follows,

```
Enter the values of a and b: 5 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "Enter the values of a and b" << endl;
cin >> a >> b;
```

Program will execute in this format now

```
Enter the values of a and b
10 20
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple!
simply use extraction(>>) operator and take multiple inputs.like this

```
int a,b,c,d;

cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
```