# C++ Split String and Double input?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, split, char

So I am new to c++ and I am workin on a Console Application right now.

I have following values:

- double x;
- string xory;

This Console Application needs the following Input:

- A or B (xory) for either length or height as Char/String.
- A double input (x) for the lenght or the height.

This should both be entered in one input.
I know I could just first enter the Char A or B and then press enter and then the next Input check for x but I want to do it in one Input

As an example if you want to Input Length is 5000 Millimeters it would look like this:

```
Input > A 5000
```

And for Height is 2000 Millimeters it should look like this:

```
Input > B 2000
```

Now after the user inputted both if it is either length or the height and x It should check if the Input was A or B and it should apply the Value to x and then output if it Length or Height and then the value x.

My issue with that is that of course I cant just do this:

```
string xory;
double x;

int main()
{
 cin >> xory + length;
  
 if (xory == "A")
 {
  xory = "length";
 }
 else if (xory == "B")
 {
  xory = "height";
 }

 cout << "the " + xory + " equals " + x;

}
```

So do I have to work with an array or do I have to split the input first so I can use it as an array and then apply it each?

Is there a simple approach for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take multiple inputs in the same line in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523835/how-to-take-multiple-inputs-in-the-same-line-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

In c++, the input stream will read characters until it sees a whitespace. So if you want to input two values in a single command line entry, separate the values by a whitespace, then call `cin` two times.

```
std::cout << "Enter a double and a string: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> xory;
std::cin >> length;
```

I would also recommend to read through the documentation on `cin`.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/